# Half line ellipsis

Tags: css

Is there a possible way to add line clamp css such that it created an ellipsis middle of the line. I have tried this :

```
-webkit-line-clamp: 2;
```

Output:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting  
text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley...
```

and

```
-webkit-line-clamp: 3;
```

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
the industry's 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley...
```

what I want is:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's the the the the the 
industry's dummy text ever since.....
```

I tried the line clamp css.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to have a line clamp that puts the ellipsis in the middle of a line directly through CSS

CSS can only control the overflow at the end of the block of text, not in the middle.

**But you can use JavaScript to do it**:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var maxLength = 50; // maximum number of characters to extract

    var el = document.querySelector('#element');
    var str = el.textContent;

    if (str.length > maxLength) {
        var strLeft = str.substring(0, maxLength / 2);
        var strRight = str.substring(str.length - maxLength / 2, str.length);

        var strWithEllipsis = strLeft + '... ' + strRight;

        el.textContent = strWithEllipsis;
    }
}
```

```html
<p id="element">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
```

Comment: @AbhishekMittal please accept answer if it meets the requirements